# Different redirects using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I run a SaaS app using CanCan for authorization (actually the more-maintained CanCanCan gem), and I want to be able to distinguish between different 'types' of permission.

E.g. if an average user accesses `/adminpanel`, that should end up with a redirect to `/` and an error flash. But if an average user accesses `/paid_feature`, I'd like to redirect them to `/payments/paid_feature/new`. It's the second one that's causing me difficulties.

Obviously I can tell CanCan to let all users access `paid_feature` in `ability.rb`, and then confirm that they've paid (and redirect if necessary) in the paid_feature controller. But that seems unclean. It's an authorization question, so I want it to be in my `ability.rb`. Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was answered by the gem's maintainer:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/123